# How do I read information from Firebase and use it in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read some information from a document in my database on Firebase using the web SDK and display that information in a React component. Here's the flow of my work:

```
render() {
let db = firebase.firestore();
let docRef = db.collection('user').doc('name');
docRef.get().then(doc => {
    console.log(doc.data());
});
return (
// HTML using data from doc.data()
);
}
```

However, I can't get the info from doc.data() outside of the callback in the .then() call. How can I use the data from doc.data() outside the callback, and render it back in React?

Comment: There's a page in the docs for handling async https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see edited lines marked with //

```
render() {
  let myData; //
  let db = firebase.firestore();
  let docRef = db.collection('user').doc('name');
  docRef.get().then(doc => {
    myData = doc.data(); //
  });
return myData; //
// or html involving myData
}
```

Comment: I used this with azium's async reference to resolve. Thanks!